Unnest Npgsql bulk query for integer array element
I have a integer[] slots in my PostgreSQL table and would like to use unnest to fill it in bulk.
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO inventory (slots) " +
                "SELECT t.slots " +
                      "FROM UNNEST(@slots) AS t(slots) " +
                      "RETURNING inventory_id";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slots", new int[10][]);0

When I try this approach (just to test 10 entries with empty array of ints), I'm getting the following error:

Error: The CRL array type System.Int32[][] isn't supported by Npgsql
or your PostgreSQL. If you wish to map it to an PostgreSQL composite
type array you need to register it before usage.

Is there a simple solution to it?
I tried to add "NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer", but to no avail.

"I have a integer[] slots" - but you're supplying int[10][] (a jagged array that is an array of 10 int[] arrays, all of which are null); did you mean instead new int[10] (an array of 10 int values, all of which are 0)?

Also do yourself a favour and use a raw or verbatim string, rather than + concatenation.

The sql column slots is integer[] ... when I tried new int[10] UNNEST makes it integer per entry, so that's not what I want.

A valid data in the record would be [1, 2, 3, 6] or [] (empty array of ints).
So with int[10][] I tried to add 10 records each with slots value being empty array of ints.
